# Find and return ex-staff but not current

Tags: mysql, sql

Given the following tables:

```
Staff
+------------+--------+
| employeeID |  name  |
+------------+--------+
|     100100 | Kelly  |
|     101010 | John   |
|     222222 | Stuart |
+------------+--------+

Academics
+------------+----------+
| employeeID | degreeID |
+------------+----------+
|     100100 | PhD      |
|     101010 | Eng      |
|     222222 | Sci      |
+------------+----------+

Class
+------------+-----------+-----------+
| employeeID | studentID | subjectID |
+------------+-----------+-----------+
|     100100 |       998 | BUS_18_2  |
|     100100 |       921 | BUS_18_2  |
|     100100 |       901 | BUS_18_2  |
|     100100 |       934 | BUS_19_1  |
|     100100 |       964 | BUS_19_2  |
|     100100 |       934 | LED_19_1  |
|     100100 |       964 | LED_19_2  |
|     101010 |       901 | COE_19_2  |
|     101010 |       874 | COE_19_2  |
|     101010 |       823 | COE_19_2  |
|     222222 |       212 | FTR_17_2  |
|     222222 |       102 | FTR_17_1  |
|     222222 |       684 | FTR_18_1  |
+------------+-----------+-----------+
```

Return a list of name and degreeIDs of all staff not holding a class in 2019

I've tried various methods around constructing nested having statements to detect if a staff member has worked in multiple years (based on counting subjectIDs), but thats more or less 'hardcoding' it and new entries could corrupt such a method (as seen in the example).

Expected result

```
+------------+------------+
|    name    | degreecode |
+------------+------------+
|   stuart   | sci        |
+------------+------------+
```

Comment: Sorry, I've amended it now to include the expected result of this sample.

Comment: Oops. Sorry, I need coffee.

Comment: And how do you know what year a class is in?

Answer (score 0):

Use correlated subquery with `not exists`

```
select distinct name, degreeid 
from staff a join academics b on a.employeeid=b.employeeid
join class c on a.employeeid=c.employeeid
where not exists 
   (select 1 from class c1 where c.employeeid=c1.employeeid and subjectID like '%_19%')
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is `not exists`.  However, your data model seems to be missing information on what classes are offered in 2019.  Assuming that `class` has this information:

```
select s.name, a.degreeid 
from staff s join
     academics a
     on s.employeeid = a.employeeid
where not exists (select 1
                  from class c
                  where c.employeeid = s.employeeid and
                        c.year = 2019
                 );
```